# Reading /dev/urandom as early as possible

Tags: linux, random, kernel, boot, entropy

I am performing research in the field of random number generation and I need to demonstrate the "boot-time entropy hole" from the well-known "P's and Q's" paper ([here](https://factorable.net/weakkeys12.extended.pdf)).  We will be spooling up two copies of the same minimal Linux virtual machine at the same time and we are expecting their /dev/urandom values to be the same at some early point in the boot process.

However, I have been unable to read /dev/urandom early enough in the boot process to spot the issue.  We need to the earlier in the boot process.

How can I get the earliest possible values of /dev/urandom?  We likely will need to modify the kernel, but we have very little experience there, and need some pointers.  Or, if there's a kernel-instrumenting tool available that could do it without re-compiling a kernel, that would be great, too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Modify the `urandom` device driver to save its first value somewhere when it starts up, and write a simple `ioctl` that retrieves it.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, that sounds like a great idea, and I hadn't come across that idea yet in my search, but could you point me to somewhere that would explain exactly how to go about that?  Myself and my group are relatively unfamiliar with kernel development and, while we feel competent enough to make the necessary modifications, we simply need to know where to begin.  The kernel is pretty understandable, but the source itself is a huge place to search around.

Comment: No idea, but I would guess that the entire `urandom` device driver is just one source file somewhere.

Comment: Google "source code of /dev/urandom"

Comment: Thanks, and I have the source code of the whole kernel, and I've been poring through it for a handle on where to begin.  So I've got the source, it's simply a matter of finding where it gets mounted and reading immediately thereafter.  But I'm unfamiliar, so that's become an issue.

Comment: I would expect there to be a source file called something like `urandom.c`.

Comment: Well, I believe I have it, it's at drivers/char/random.c.  It defines /dev/random and /dev/urandom, according to it's comments, but I'm unsure where at.  This is where I'm missing something.  I'm not even sure that I'd recognize it if I saw it.  Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urandom` is provided via device driver and the first thing kernel does with the driver is to call `init` call.

If you take a look here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c#L1401

```
  * Note that setup_arch() may call add_device_randomness()
  * long before we get here. This allows seeding of the pools
  * with some platform dependent data very early in the boot
  * process. But it limits our options here. We must use
  * statically allocated structures that already have all
  * initializations complete at compile time. We should also
  * take care not to overwrite the precious per platform data
  * we were given.
  */
 static int rand_initialize(void)
 {
         init_std_data(&input_pool);
         init_std_data(&blocking_pool);
         init_std_data(&nonblocking_pool);
         return 0;
 }
 early_initcall(rand_initialize);
```

So, `init` function for this driver is `rand_initialize`. However note that comment says that `setup_arch` may call `add_device randomness()` before this device is even initialized. However, calling that function *does not* add any actual entropy (it feeds the pool with stuff like MAC addresses, so if you have two exactly the same VMs, you're good there). From the comment:

```
  * add_device_randomness() is for adding data to the random pool that
  * is likely to differ between two devices (or possibly even per boot).
  * This would be things like MAC addresses or serial numbers, or the
  * read-out of the RTC. This does *not* add any actual entropy to the
  * pool, but it initializes the pool to different values for devices
  * that might otherwise be identical and have very little entropy
  * available to them (particularly common in the embedded world).
```

Also, note that entropy pools are stored on shutdown and restored on boot time via init script (on my Ubuntu 14.04, it's in `/etc/init.d/urandom`), so you might want to call your script from that script before

```
 53     (
 54       date +%s.%N
 55 
 56       # Load and then save $POOLBYTES bytes,
 57       # which is the size of the entropy pool
 58       if [ -f "$SAVEDFILE" ]
 59       then
 60           cat "$SAVEDFILE"
 61       fi
 62     # Redirect output of subshell (not individual commands)
 63     # to cope with a misfeature in the FreeBSD (not Linux)
 64     # /dev/random, where every superuser write/close causes
 65     # an explicit reseed of the yarrow.
 66     ) >/dev/urandom
```

or similar call is made.